# Filter two Flux<T> based on member variable in reactive programming

Tags: spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have two flux and need to filter master flux from the other flux to create another flux. I need to filter masterflux data from secondflux based on name property to get new flux in a reactive way.

```
class Master{
private String name;
private Long id;
}

class second{
private String name;
}

masterflux.filterWhen(s->s.getName().equals(secondflux.??)) // Need Help
```

Answer (score 0):

`filterWhen` operator accepts a `Function` with result type of `Publisher<Boolean>`:

```
filterWhen(Function<? super T,? extends Publisher<Boolean>> asyncPredicate)
```

So, you have to filter the `secondFlux` asynchronously like this:

```java
Flux<Master> filtered = masterflux.filterWhen(master -> 
        secondflux.filter(second -> master.getName().equals(second.getName())).hasElements());
```